# Filtering based on the last two current values in Java rx

Tags: java, filter, reactive-programming

I'm trying to build a simple application using java reactive extensions. I have two streams that emits temperature values continuously, I want to detect and filter out spikes of sensed temperature that could be errors, for doing so I need to take account of the precedent value too so that I can take account of the variation like so:

[image: filtering on pairs idea]

Still I was unable to find the right operator in the documentation. Has anybody any idea of how can I accomplish the task? Should I make a custom operator?

These are my streams:

```
double min = 50, max = 75, spikeFreq = 0.01;
    Observable<Double> tempStream1 = Observable.create((
            Subscriber<? super Double> subscriber) -> {
        new TempStream(subscriber, min, max, spikeFreq).start();
    });

    Observable<Double> tempStream2 = Observable.create((
            Subscriber<? super Double> subscriber) -> {
        new TempStream(subscriber, min, max, spikeFreq).start();
    });

public class TempStream extends Thread{

private Subscriber<? super Double> subscriber;
private TempSensor sensor;

public TempStream(Subscriber<? super Double> subscriber, double min,
        double max, double spikeFreq) {
    this.subscriber = subscriber;
    sensor = new TempSensor(min, max, spikeFreq);
}

    @Override
    public void run() {
        Random gen = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        while (!subscriber.isUnsubscribed()) {
            try {
                subscriber.onNext(sensor.getCurrentValue());
                Thread.sleep(1000 + gen.nextInt() % 1000);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                subscriber.onError(ex);
            }
        }
        subscriber.onCompleted();
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems there is no operator to perform that. However, you can `publish` the stream, and `zip` it with *itself.`drop(1)`* to obtain a stream of pairs of values. That one will be easy to filter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Perhaps the `buffer` operator (http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/buffer.html) might help in this case. 
You want to use `buffer` with `count = 2` and `skip = 1`. That way you'll get a "lookahead" of one element on the stream.

E.g.:

```
stream.buffer(2,1).filter(buf -> buf.size() == 2 && buf.get(0) - buf.get(1) < max);
```

Notice that this example also checks whether two values were buffered since it might happen that only one is emitted upon completion of the stream.

Comment: How to pair with previous starting with the first (so previous would be optional and the first time it's emitted it's null)? Using scan probably?

Comment: This does not repeat values in the spike check. For example, stream of `10,20,35,40` will emit `[10,20]` and `[35,40]` instead of `[10,20]`, `[20,35]`, and `[35,40]`

Comment: @Aarjav The doc seems to be wrong. I got  [10,20], [20,35], and [35,40]  when I tried to run the code.

Answer (score 0):

It might be achieved using `scan` operator:

```
 val max = `your value`

 stream
    .scan(Pair(Int.MAX_VALUE, Int.MAX_VALUE)) { t1, t2 -> t1.second to t2 }
    .skip(1)
    .filter { (previous, current) -> current - previous < max }
    .map { it.second }
```

So build pairs of items, previous to current.

- Skip initial value
- For the first element `previous` will be `Int.MAX_VALUE` which always passes filter `current - previous < max`.
- other elements are real prev/current pairs
- get current item for pairs which passes the filter

Less clear, but encapsulated:

```
/** emits first item, then emits only if current value passes [filter] */
fun <T : Any> Observable<T>.filterWithPrevious(filter: (previous: T, current: T) -> Boolean): Observable<T> =
    scan(Pair(null, null)) { t1: Pair<T?, T?>, t2: T -> t1.second to t2 }
        .skip(1)
        .filter { (first, second) -> first?.let { filter(it, second!!) } ?: true }
        .map { it.second!! }
```

and then:

```
stream.filterWithPrevious { previous, current -> current - previous < max }
```

PS: I've written it on kotlin, for java it will be the same but verbose.